# Calculate MBR & MAR from Memory Organization

Tags: memory, assembly

I want to ask how can we claculate the:

- MBR ( Memory Buffer register ) size
- MAR ( Memory address register ) size
- number of data lines

when knowing the number of address lines and the memory capacity ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask. Is MBR same as MDR (Memory Data Register)?

Comment: Are we talking about microprogramming? What's the memory capacity here? Something like if you have 4GB memory and 30 address lines, that'd suggest 1 GW memory where word is 32-bit?

Comment: @turboscrew yes exactly this , it's Assembly Language

Comment: Not really assembly. Rather microcode.